# jQuery selector vs each

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I have these two pieces of code - **which are identical**. Also lets assume that the '.selector' returns atleast 2 objects.

**Snippet 1**

```
$('.selector').myMethod();
```

**Snippet 2**

```
$('.selector').each(function(){
    $(this).myMethod();
});
```

Lets say for each one of the 'selected' returned objects I want to pass in the objects id wrapped up to `myMethod()`.

So **Snippet 2** could become

```
$('.selector').each(function(){
    $(this).myMethod({attribute: $(this).attr('id')});
});
```

How can I do something similar with **Snippet 1** (i.e without using `$.each()`)? 

For obvious reasons this isn't correct

```
$('.selector').myMethod({attribute: $(this).attr('id')});
```

as `$(this)` does not represent any one of the 'selected' returned object.

**EDIT:** In **Snippet 1** Is there any way to reference the returned object as jQuery itself 'loops' through each returned object and calls the method. (again w/o `$.each()`).

Comment: You can't...you'd have to loop... how else would you run a method that takes 1 ID on multiple ID's but only calling once?

Comment: If it really is your own code, you have direct access to each element involved. You'll have to explain why that isn't good enough, or state that "myMethod" isn't really your own code.

Comment: Some jQuery functions accept a function as a parameter, and that function receives context as parameter(s). I think that may be what you're getting at. See http://api.jquery.com/addclass/, the version that accepts a function.

Comment: ^ You could change `myMethod` so that it understands `$('.selector').myMethod({attribute: function() { return $(this).attr('id'); } });` or `$('.selector').myMethod(function() { return {attribute: $(this).attr('id');} });`

Comment: I like @FelixKling's thought process here, but all it does is moves the loop to `myFunction()`. I have done that quite a bit in the past, especially when `myFunction()` can be applied to many different collections during the course of an application. The bottom line is if you want to apply an unique function to each object in the collection you will have to loop somewhere.

Comment: Or maybe I misunderstood the question. Regarding *"as jQuery itself 'loops' through each returned object and calls the method"* No, that's not what jQuery is doing. It calls `myMethod()` only once and passes the complete set to the method. The method itself then has to decide how it applies its functionality to each element in the set (e.g. via `.each`).

Comment: This all depends on what `$.fn.myMethod` does!  When I make jQuery plugins, I do `$.fn.myMethod = function(){ return this.each(function(){}); }`.  This is how a lot of jQuery stuff works, it uses `.each` *internally*.

Comment: @FelixKling @apsillers. Does `.method()` get called individually for each returned object or is `method()` called once and the whole matched set is passed in. I thought it is called once for each element.

Comment: Nope, it's called once per set. See http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/, especially http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#using-the-each-method

Answer (score 1):

The two pieces of code ***are not identical***. One is a collection of objects and the other is a loop through a collection of objects. You can take an action on a collection that affect all equally *or* you can act individually on each object in the collection. Once you invoke the `each()` function you are individualizing objects in the collection.

To answer your question, there is no way to reference the returned *collection of objects* as if you were looping and applying a different function, calculation or result to each individual item in the collection.

Comment: I think he's speaking in terms of the result. `$('.myclass').addClass('active')` and `$('.myclass').each(function() { $(this).addClass('active'); });` will give the same result.

Comment: True @JasonP and that speaks to when you should use `each()` vs. acting on the collection.